# How can I define a llvm BitmaskEnum in td file?

Tags: llvm

I want convert a enum type class `GType` to `BitMaskEnum`in td file. But can not find any example used in llvm source.

My original enum class is defined as follow in td file:

```
def GA : I32EnumAttrCase<"A", 0>;
def GB : I32EnumAttrCase<"B", 1>;
def GC : I32EnumAttrCase<"C", 2>;
def GD : I32EnumAttrCase<"D", 3>;
def GE : I32EnumAttrCase<"E", 4>;
def GType : I32EnumAttr<"GType", "G type", [GA, GB, GC, GD, GE]> {
  let genSpecializedAttr = 0;
  let cppNamespace = "::foo::bar";
}
def GTypeAttr : Enum<X_Dialect, GType, "GType">;
```

Then generated class as follow:

```
enum class GType : uint32_t {
  A = 0,
  B = 1,
  C = 2,
  D = 3,
  E = 4,
};
```

I only found `enableBitmaskEnumInNamespace = true;` in some td file in llvm src code. But seems not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I found it is different way that use BitEnum in td MLIR and BitMaskEnum in source file.
I found `I32BitEnumAttrCase` and `I32BitEnumAttr` in `mlir/IR/EnumAttr.td`, so I try change original code in this:

```
def GA : I32BitEnumAttrCase<"A", 0>;
def GB : I32BitEnumAttrCase<"B", 1>;
def GC : I32BitEnumAttrCase<"C", 2>;
def GD : I32BitEnumAttrCase<"D", 3>;
def GE : I32BitEnumAttrCase<"E", 4>;
def GType : I32BitEnumAttr<"GType", "G type", [GA, GB, GC, GD, GE]> {
  let genSpecializedAttr = 0;
  let cppNamespace = "::foo::bar";
}
def GTypeAttr : Enum<X_Dialect, GType, "GType">;
```

The generated class `GraphGridType` is no change, but 3 new functions were generated:

- `GType operator|(GType lhs, GType rhs)`
- `GType operator&(GType lhs, GType rhs)`
- `bool bitEnumContains(GType bits, GType bit)`

These 3 function is enough for test a GType's value.